# Ubuntu Server 22.04 on Alienware Aurora R13

Tags: server, 22.04, alienware

I'm in the process of setting up node computers for a new blockchain project. It needs Ubuntu Server 22.04 as the OS. I have had no issues on a couple of more basic computers (such as a HP 600G3 i5-7500 dual core). Where I'm having an issue is with a brand new Alienware Aurora R13. It gets to the name/servername/username page, I put my details in, and then it reboots, and has a message to restart the installer. I have tried installing and also not installing the additional drivers. It is hard wired to the ethernet, so no issue with WiFi. I have set AHCI in the bios, and it seems to be quite happy using F12 for a one time USB boot override. Are NVIDIA graphics cards still an issue here, or has that been resolved?

TIA